# Unable to view existing close votes on mobile app

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, ios-app

When I've Close-Voted a question, I sometimes check back to "see how the close votes are going".  Easy enough on the main site, but just now I voted to close a question on the main site, then a few minutes later checked back on the iOS app.  Having gone to the close menu, all I could see was this:

[image: "there were no close reasons found for this question"]

Text reads: *"There were no close reasons found for this question"*

iOS App, version 1.3.1

Comment: I just got this for no apparent reason too.